# Error with latest android studio for Local aar file Direct local •aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

```
Direct local •aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR.
The resulting AAR would be broken 2 because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar 
file dependencies would not be packaged in the 2 resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android 
Gradle Plugin produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this error).
```

I tried by adding local .aar into libs directory under android project.
To fetch local aar I have added below implementation under build.gradle.kts(app level).

`implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar", "*.aar"))))`

Everything work perfectly for debug mode. Issue with release version of app. This happening with latest android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this answer for future reference.

- **Create a new directory of your project's root directory.**

[image]

- **Name your directory name like below**

[image]

- **Put your local aar into created directory**

[image]

- **Create a file with name build.gradle.kts under your local aar directory**

[image]

- **After creating build.gradle.kts, It will be like this.**

[image]

- **Add below code inside build.gradle.kts and replace sample_logger_1.0.0.aar
  with your aar name. Click sync now.**

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default",file("sample_logger_1.0.0.aar"))
```

- **Include your local aar directory inside your setting.gradle. Click sync now**

```
 include(":my-local-sdk")
```

- **Implement your local aar inside build.gradle (Module:app) of your project**

```
implementation(project(":my-local-sdk"))
```